# Java minimax on dots and boxs game

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm trying to implement an AI that uses Minimax for the dots and boxs game (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes)

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public Line makeMove(GameState gs) {
    if (gs.getRemainingLines().size() == 1) {
        return gs.getRemainingLines().get(0);
    }

    if (gs.getPlayer() == 1) {
        int minscore = -1;
        GameState g = gs.clone();
        Line lnew = null;
        List<Line> l = gs.getRemainingLines();
        for (Line l2 : l) {
            g.addLine(l2);
            if (evaluate(g) > minscore) {
                minscore = (evaluate(g));
                lnew = l2;
            }
        }
        return lnew;
    } else {
        int maxscore = 999;
        GameState g = gs.clone();
        Line lnew = null;
        List<Line> l = gs.getRemainingLines();
        for (Line l2 : l) {
            g.addLine(l2);
            if (evaluate(g) < maxscore) {
                maxscore = (evaluate(g));
                lnew = l2;
            }
        }
        return lnew;
    }

}
```

However, it keeps returning `null` and I don't think I'm impementing minimax correctly. Can anyone give me some pointers.

`getRemainingLines()` returns a List of moves that are still possible.

`evaluate()` returns an int for the score.

Comment: Can you trace your evaluate function?

Comment: what does your nullpointer exception look like?  can you include the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you completely re-factor your code. The problem with looking at your code (and why there haven't been many responses here) is that it's hard to follow and hard to debug. For instance, what is `gs.getRemainingLines` and what does it do exactly? (Why remaining lines and not all legal lines?)

But, with some simplifications it will be much easier to figure out what is going on and to fix it.

At an abstract level minimax is just this procedure:

```
float minimax_max(GameState g)
{
    if (g is terminal or max depth reached)
        return eval(g);

    float bestVal = -inf;
    bestMove = null;

    moves = g->getLegalMoves();
    for (m : moves)
    {
        ApplyMove(m);
        if (g->nextPlayer == maxPlayer)
            nextVal = minimax_max(g);
        else
            nextVal = minimax_min(g);
        if (nextVal > bestVal)
        {
            bestVal = nextVal;
            bestMove = m;
        }
        UndoMove(m);
    }

    return bestVal;
}
```

I haven't shown exactly how to get/use the last move at the end, but it isn't that hard. You also need another procedure for `minimax_min`, or you can put an if statement into the code.

If you look at your code, you've written it close to this, but you've left a lot of game specific details in the code. But, *you shouldn't have to think about those things to get minimax working correctly*.

In particular, most games can be reasoned with abstractly if you provide functions for `GetMoves()`, `ApplyMove()`, `UndoMove()`, and `eval()`, which evaluates a state. (Further search enhancements would require more functions, but this will get you a long ways.)

Some reasons why you might want to re-factor in this way:

- You can now test minimax and your other code separately.
- You can test your dots and boxes code by validating that all legal moves are generated and that after applying a move you have a legal state with the correct player moving next. (You can play and undo long sequences of random moves to help validate that you always end up back in the start state afterwards.)
- You can test your evaluation function easily on individual states to make sure it works properly. (In practice you can't usually search to the end of the game to determine the winner.)
- You can test minimax by using a simple evaluation function and testing to see if the right moves are made. (e.g. if you prefer moves on the edges, a 1-ply search should return a move on the edge)
- Other people can read your code more easily. We can look at each piece of code and see if it is correct on its own, instead of having to mix the game-specific implementation details into the minimax-specific details.
- If you can apply and undo moves properly, you don't need to make copies of the game states. This will make the code much more efficient.

While you could try to fix your code without refactoring (e.g. just find the first place it returns null, and that will point out where your error is), in the long term your code will be hard to debug and improve without these changes.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is that gs.getRemainingLines() actually has lines remaining.

A separate problem is that you are adding every line to the `GameState g` to check. You either need to remove each added line after calling evaluate or put the clone inside the loop at the top such as

```
int minscore = -1;
Line lnew = null;
List<Line> l = gs.getRemainingLines();
for (Line l2 : l) {
    GameState g = gs.clone();
    g.addLine(l2);
    if (evaluate(g) > minscore) {
        minscore = (evaluate(g));
        lnew = l2;
    }
}
```

or

```
int minscore = -1;
GameState g = gs.clone();
Line lnew = null;
List<Line> l = gs.getRemainingLines();
for (Line l2 : l) {
    g.addLine(l2);
    if (evaluate(g) > minscore) {
        minscore = (evaluate(g));
        lnew = l2;
    }
    g.removeLine(l2);
}
```

However if you are trying to use minimax (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) then you will need to change your code to recursively call makeMove (unless you modify the algorithm to do determine the min-max using loop constructs).

```
public GameState makeMove(GameState gs) {
   if (gs.getRemainingLines().size() == 1) {
       GameState g = gs.clone();
       g.addLine(gs.getRemainingLines().get(0));
       return g;
   }

   if (gs.getPlayer() == 1) {
       GameState g = gs.clone();
       g.setPlayer(2);
       int bestValue = -1;
       Line lbest = null;
       List<Line> lines = gs.getRemainingLines();
       for (Line line : lines) {
           g.addLine(line);
           GameState val = makeMove(g);
           g.removeLine(line);
           if (evaluate(val) > bestValue) {
               bestValue = evaluate(g);
               lbest = line;
           }
       }
       g.addLine(lbest);
       return g;
   } else {
       GameState g = gs.clone();
       g.setPlayer(1);
       int bestValue = 999;
       Line lbest = null;
       List<Line> lines = gs.getRemainingLines();
       for (Line line : lines) {
           g.addLine(line);
           GameState val = makeMove(g);
           g.removeLine(line);
           if (evaluate(val) < bestValue) {
               bestValue = evaluate(g);
               lbest = line;
           }
       }
       g.addLine(lbest);
       return g;
   }

}
```

Comment: Won't the for loop only run through each element once so it doesn't need to remove them?

Comment: From what I can tell, your makeMove method is attempting to find the move of adding a single line that will return either the minimum or maximum score depending on whether you are player one or not (btw the minscore/maxscore variables are misnamed since they are actually each attempting to find the opposite of what they are named). The loop is going to iterate over every remaining line should check if it is the 'optimal' score for the gameboard if you add that line which will require you to remove the previous one.

Comment: Typo correction: The loop is going to iterate over every remaining line and should check if adding the line is the 'optimal' score for the gameboard which will requires removing the previous line in order to just check one line being added to the gameboard not all the lines.

Comment: The method is meant to find the best move for each player. I'm still not sure how I would change it so that it would be right.

Comment: If you just want to find the best move for each player then you don't need the if/else block (if (gs.getPlayer() == 1) {). Just always do what is in the if. The else is finding the move that will give the minimum score. You also need to do what I said in the answer. However there is no random element in your makeMove method so you are always going to get the same results.

Comment: won't the best move differ depending on which player it is ?

Comment: No, in dots and boxes players score solely based on completing boxes. The simplistic 'best' move will be the move that completes the most number of boxes. Ideally the 'best' move will also be the move that allows the least number of boxes to be completed by the other player. The algorithm will need to look at more than just the current move to determine that though.

Comment: I don't really understand sorry.  Can you show me an example please?

Comment: Did the updated example showing how to use minimax help?